# How to populate Listview in one of the pages of a ViewPager layout

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a very basic question about ViewPager. I have a ViewPagerActivity that includes 5 pages, where each page has its own layout xml, in addition to the main.xml (see code below) that is referenced in the ViewPagerActivity.java's setContentView(R.layout.main).

The "middle" page (middle.xml which is one of the 5 layout xml's) includes a Listview that is dynamically populated with data from a database.

Here is my question. Where should I put the following code that pupulates the Listview and set ClickListener?

```
mMemoListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_in_middle_layout);
mMemoListAdapter = new MemoListAdapter(this);
mMemoListView.setAdapter(mMemoListAdapter);
mMemoListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
         viewMemo(position);
}
   });
```

I don't think it will be in ViewPagerActivity.java, unless it can reference both main.xml and middle.xml through setContentView(). I also thought about adding a java class that will reference middle.xml, but I don't know how it can be activated(?) when the middle page is inflated. (See MyPageAdapter below to see how each page is inflated.)

Thanks for reading. Please feel free to ask for further clarification.

Here is main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is middle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffffff"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    >
    <com.ViewPager.TitleBackgroundButton
        android:id="@+id/titleBackgroundBtn"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Memo"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_in_middle_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>
<com.ViewPager.TitleBitmapButton
android:id="@+id/newMemoBtn"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:text="New"
android:textSize="18dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ff420000"
/>
<com.ViewPager.TitleBitmapButton
android:id="@+id/closeBtn"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:text="Close"
android:textSize="18dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ff420000"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is ViewPagerActivity.java

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public static final String TAG = "ViewPagerActivity";
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
            ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
            myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            myPager.setCurrentItem(2);

    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            public int getCount() {
                    return 5;
            }

            public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    int resId = 0;
                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                            resId = R.layout.farleft;
                            break;
                    case 1:
                            resId = R.layout.left;
                            break;
                    case 2:
                            resId = R.layout.middle;
                            break;
                    case 3:
                            resId = R.layout.right;
                            break;
                    case 4:
                            resId = R.layout.farright;
                            break;
                    }

                    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

                    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

                    return view;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
                    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

            }

            @Override
            public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
                    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

            }

            @Override
            public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public Parcelable saveState() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

    }
```

Comment: You may want to consider to make your `MyPagerAdapter` extend the [`FragmentPagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) from the support library. That way you'll be able to abstract the logic of every page into a self-contained `Fragment`. That will probably make things much more manageable in the long run, especially if you're planning on adding more pages later on. The link to the documentation also contains an code example.

Comment: Can you take a look at my question on Fragment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967435/pageradapter-vs-fragmentstatepageradapter ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add it in your switch case in instantiateItem:

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {


                View view=null;

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                int resId = 0;
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                        resId = R.layout.farleft;
                        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                        break;
                case 1:
                        resId = R.layout.left;
                        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                        break;
                case 2:
                        resId = R.layout.middle;
                        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                        ListView memoListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_in_middle_layout);
                        MemoListAdapter memoListAdapter = new MemoListAdapter(this);
                        memoListView.setAdapter(memoListAdapter);

                        break;
                case 3:
                        resId = R.layout.right;
                        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                        break;
                case 4:
                        resId = R.layout.farright;
                        view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
                        break;
                }



                ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

                return view;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Should I put the ClickListener code there as well?

Comment: Also the "new MemoListAdapter(this)" part is causing an error "The constructor MemoListAdapter(ViewPagerActivity.MyPagerAdapter) is undefined". Should I use something other than "this" as the argument? FYI. The constructor in MemoListAdapter is defined as " public MemoListAdapter(Context context) {
  mContext = context;
 }"

Comment: Yes you should set the clicklistener and mContext in the constructor :)

Comment: If the code looks like you posted above you should add the following constructor: new MemoListAdapter(ViewPagerActivity.this);