# PagerAdapter vs FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I downloaded a sample ViewPager project from http://files.mail.ru/EZU6G4, and modified it for my test app. The project I downloaded uses FragmentStatePagerAdapter as the argument in mViewPager.setAdapter(mFragmentsAdapter) in the main activity java file, and works just fine.

However, I used the same mViewPager.setAdapter code in my app, but the "setAdapter" part is redlined and I get the following message.

"The method setAdapter(PagerAdapter) in the type ViewPager is not applicable for the arguments (MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter)"

I'm surprised that the same code works in one project, but not in another. Please help me find why it is.

For your reference, below is the setAdapter method definition in the ViewPager.java file that both projects use.

```
public void setAdapter(PagerAdapter adapter) {
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.setDataSetObserver(null);
        mAdapter.startUpdate(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
            final ItemInfo ii = mItems.get(i);
            mAdapter.destroyItem(this, ii.position, ii.object);
        }
        mAdapter.finishUpdate(this);
        mItems.clear();
        removeAllViews();
        mCurItem = 0;
        scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    mAdapter = adapter;

    if (mAdapter != null) {
        if (mObserver == null) {
            mObserver = new DataSetObserver();
        }
        mAdapter.setDataSetObserver(mObserver);
        mPopulatePending = false;
        if (mRestoredCurItem >= 0) {
            mAdapter.restoreState(mRestoredAdapterState, mRestoredClassLoader);
            setCurrentItemInternal(mRestoredCurItem, false, true);
            mRestoredCurItem = -1;
            mRestoredAdapterState = null;
            mRestoredClassLoader = null;
        } else {
            populate();
        }
    }
```

ViewPagerActivity.java

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {


public static final String TAG = "ViewPagerActivity";
private MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter mFragmentsAdapter ;
private ViewPager mViewPager ;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            mFragmentsAdapter = new MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);

            mViewPager.setAdapter(mFragmentsAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Does your `MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter` extend the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` class? Also, double check your imports are correct.

Comment: Yes it does. From what I see, the imports are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the Android Support Library. If you are using that, make sure you use the `Fragment` classes from the support lib instead of the standard Android distribution.